# Getting wrong values from MySQL through PHP PDO driver on some machines

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I have a MySQL InnoDB table with float (8,2) field. It stores value `7221.00`

I'm using Laravel. When retrieving data from the database, I noticed that I get `7200` instead of `7221.00`. On our team, two developers report having the same issue, but other two developers do not have this problem - they see correct value.

While debugging through Laravel code, I found out that the data is wrong right after reading from PDO fetchAll().

We have compared our MySQL and php_pdo_mysql.dll versions between working and broken server configurations. While we see the difference, we are not sure where to find the real culprit and whether we should upgrade or downgrade our PHP, PDO, MySQL or all of them.

Here are our observations.

One of **broken** servers:

MySQL:

```
protocol_version    10
version 5.1.41-log
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine ia32
version_compile_os  Win32
```

php_pdo_mysql.dll file version:

```
5.6.4.0
```

One of **working** servers:

MySQL:

```
protocol_version 10
version 5.6.20
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86
version_compile_os Win32
```

php_pdo_mysql.dll file version:

```
5.5.15.0
```

To make things even more confusing, it is possible to store any value from the broken server through the same PHP application through Laravel and PDO, and the value `7221.00` gets stored correctly (verified through SQLYog). Also an SQL query in SQLYog returns correct value. It is only reading operation in our application which gets it wrong on some servers.

**What is wrong with our broken servers? Where is the culprit of turning `7221.00` to `7200` ?**

Comment: I specifically remember a situation like this happened in my team not so long ago. The problem wasn't PDO, but the values stored in the DB. Long story short, use Decimal instead of float.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei, I have seen similar advice on some other sites. But it is confusing why on some servers exactly the same database works fine.

Comment: I'd love to be able to answer that, but it's a bit beyond my pay grade. Now that you mentioned it I'm kind of curios too...